# Tomcat AJP request to normal HTTP

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, ajp

I have a company application deployed on Tomcat 8 and another application making request to an Apache server that uses AJP ` protocol to access the application. I am new to AJP. I have created an AWS infrastructure using containers with the mentioned application (as an alternative to the described above). The problem is I want to avoid using Apache and use Amazon's ALB (application load balancer) and so far it's working, except the AJP request. The problem I am having is that when not using Apache, I do not need to use AJP anymore and I want to replace it with HTTPS. Will enabling the HTTPS connector in Tomcat do the trick? The lines in Apache configuration are:

```
ProxyPass               /pmaddon-a  ajp://*.*.*.*:8009/pmaddon-a
ProxyPassReverse        /pmaddon-a  ajp://*.*.*.*:8009/pmaddon-a
```

To sum up, if I skip the Apache server and call Tomcat directly with HTTPS (with enabled HTTPS connector of course) will it have the same result as using the AJP connector as I am now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you want to do is:

- Access you application directly using the TOMCAT connector
- Remove the APACHE in front and its AJP communication with TOMCAT

This is possible to do, perhaps you need to adapt that other application (the one that calls apache) to point to the URL that arrives to the TOMCAT connector.

If the question is if you will have the same result:

I understand yes. AJP and HTTP both serve the same content, it's just a different protocol.

You didnt explain if you have HA therefore I did not enter that topic.

Answer (score 1):

AJP is very similar to http/https except it is a binary protocol from Apache (Apache Jserv Protocol) but it is better performant since it size is almost 1/5 of the http/https.
It is widely being used with reverse proxy web server where webserver talk to application server using AJB.

You don't need to stick with AJP if you are directly connecting to Tomcat connector